# Export Graphviz files from Eclipse as .png

Tags: eclipse, uml, graphviz, plantuml

I am using Context Mapper to generate context maps in the Eclipse IDE. To visualize these maps, context mapper uses Graphviz and PlantUML to create images in a .puml file in a src-gen folder inside my Eclipse project.

I am currently trying to find a way to export these images from Eclipse and the .puml file format into a .png format that can be used inside my research report. The [Context Mapper documentation](https://contextmapper.org/docs/plant-uml/) only refers to Markdown and pandoc, but does not indicate any ways to get there.

Any ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Answered. Eclipse allows to export .png image files by simply right-clicking on the .puml files. Solved.